# Show that $\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x) \to f(x)$ uniformly on $E$.

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following:

> Let $E$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ be a real-valued function defined on $E$. Suppose that $f_n$ is a sequence of bounded functions on $E$ which converges to $f$ uniformly on E. Show that as n $\to \infty$,
>
> $\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x) \to f(x)$ uniformly on $E$.

I know that uniform converges implies pointwise converges, but this doesn't seem like much help here.

If $f_n(x)$ was continuous, it would make the problem a bit easier, but I have no idea if this is the case.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Rough idea: uniform convergence gives you $|f_k(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for $k>N$. Then split the sum (for $n>N$) into two parts: up to $N$ and the sum from $N$ to $n$. The latter part can be bounded by the uniform convergence conditions and the first part has a $1/n$ in front to ensure it will be small.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now I think!

Comment: That's the standard good-part/bad-part technique which occurs often in proving convergence in various ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $p\in\mathbb{N}^*$ such that $|f_k(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in E$ and $k\geqslant p$. Now, if$x\in E$
$$ \left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{f_k(x)}-f(x)\right|\leqslant\frac{1}{n}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{(f_k(x)-f(x))}\right|+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=p}^n{\underbrace{|f_k(x)-f(x)|}_{\varepsilon}} $$
For $n$ large enough $$ \frac{1}{n}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{(f_k(x)-f(x))}\right|<\varepsilon $$
so that $$ \left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{f_k(x)}-f(x)\right|<2\varepsilon $$